How can I delete all database entities after the tests are completed?
I was looking if there is a way with some kind of annotation rather than with code to clean the database after a test generated registries in it. I found about @Dirtiescontext but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't know if I'm not using it right or what the problem is. I am using Spring Boot 3 and MySQL 8.
This is my test code:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisplayName("Articles Integration Tests")
public class ArticlesControllerIT {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private ArticlesService articlesService;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @Test
    @Sql("/create_suppliers.sql")
    @DisplayName("Happy path: Create articles")
    void WHEN_calling_create_articles_THEN_status_is_200() {
        final List<ArticleDTO> articleDTOS = Instancio.ofList(ArticleDTO.class).size(3)
                .ignore(field(ArticleDTO::getId))
                .ignore(field(ArticleDTO::getCategory))
                .supply(all(SupplierDTO.class), random -> SupplierDTO.builder()
                        .id(random.intRange(1, 10))
                        .build())
                .create();
        final CreateArticlesRequest createArticlesRequest = CreateArticlesRequest.builder()
                .articles(articleDTOS)
                .user(Instancio.create(String.class))
                .build();
        final ResponseEntity<CreateArticlesResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(restTemplate.getRootUri() + URIConstants.ARTICLES_URI,
                HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(createArticlesRequest), new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
        final List<ArticleDTO> articles = Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody()).getArticles();

        //Remove ID from the response articicles to check that content is the same as the articles to be created
        articles.forEach(article -> article.setId(null));

        assertEquals(articles.size(), articleDTOS.size() , "articles.size() should be " + articleDTOS.size());
        assertTrue(articles.containsAll(articleDTOS), "articles should contain the same elements as articulosDTOS");
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode(), "Status Code should be " + HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

My service method that creates the registries:
@Service
public class ArticlesServiceImpl implements ArticlesService {
    private final ArticleRepository articleRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final SuppliersService suppliersService;

    @Autowired
    ArticlesServiceImpl(final ArticleRepository articleRepository, final ModelMapper modelMapper, final SuppliersService suppliersService) {
        this.articleRepository = articleRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
        this.suppliersService = suppliersService;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> createArticles(final List<Article> articles, final String usuario) {
        final List<ArticleDAO> articleDAOS;

        this.suppliersService.checkSuppliersExist(articles
                .stream()
                .map(Article::getSupplier)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        this.checkArticlesDontExistByName(articles);
        articles.forEach(article -> article.setUser(usuario));
        articleDAOS = this.modelMapper.map(articles, new TypeToken<List<ArticleDAO>>(){}.getType());
        this.articleRepository.saveAll(articleDAOS);
        return this.modelMapper.map(articleDAOS, new TypeToken<List<Article>>(){}.getType());
    }
}

My repository:
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<ArticleDAO, Integer> {
    boolean existsByName(final String name);
}

My entity:
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "article")
public class ArticleDAO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "selling_price")
    private BigDecimal sellingPrice;

    @Column(name = "supplier_price")
    private BigDecimal supplierPrice;

    @Column(name = "user")
    private String user;

    @Column(name = "selling_unit_type")
    private String sellingUnitType;

    @Column(name = "inventory_amount")
    private Integer inventoryAmount;

    @Column(name = "picture")
    private String picture;

    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @Column(name = "reference")
    private String reference;

    @Column(name = "bar_code")
    private String barCode;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CategoryDAO category;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SupplierDAO supplier;
}

Am I using @DirtiesContext wrong, or this is just not the way?

usually you only mock the database during testing

I am doing integration tests in a Docker environment and with other microservices so it's not a scenario where I'd mock the db alike in unit testing @nbk

Whether the @DirtiesContext annotation will clean persisted data in the test database depends on how you create this database in the test.
If you are using embedded H2 in-memory database, then @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) will cause Spring to discard the ApplicationContext and create a new one after each test method, including the destruction and re-creation of the H2 in-memory database, so it effectively "cleans" the database state between tests. But if you create your test database, for example, using Testcontainers, then @DirtiesContext will not necessarily affect the test container with the database.
I would recommend using SQL scripts to clean up the database after each test with the @Sql annotation, just like you do to create test data:
@Sql(scripts = "/truncateTables.sql", executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)

From my point of view, this is the most reliable method.
There is also an option to use @Transactional annotation to rollback test transaction after each test, but this option will not work for you due to loading the real web environment using SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT. More info about it in the documentation:

If your test is @Transactional, it rolls back the transaction at the
end of each test method by default. However, as using this arrangement
with either RANDOM_PORT or DEFINED_PORT implicitly provides a real
servlet environment, the HTTP client and server run in separate
threads and, thus, in separate transactions. Any transaction initiated
on the server does not roll back in this case.


thanks! the @Sql way is a good one in my case since I'm doing integration tests using microservices, docker and a test mysql db so it seems DirtiesContext won't be of any help here
